# Passing an array as a parameter with default values into int main()

Tags: c++, parameters, default-value

I am having difficulty passing an array as an argument into `int main()` with default values.
For example:

```
int main(int a){}
```

works wonderfully. As does

```
int main(int a = 1){}
```

Passing `int main()` an array also works wonderfully:

```
int main(int a[3])
```

**However, combining these two concepts seems break:**

```
int main(int a[1] = {0,1})
```

After a significant amount of [googleing](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=c%2B%2B+parameter+default+value+array&cp=33&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=c%2B%2B+parameter+default+value+array&pbx=1&fp=ac5229e2e8efe107), I haven't found a solution.

*please help me SO, you're my only hope!*

## EDIT

The purpose of this, in short, is to make my code as little lines as possible, for a challenge my professor recently issued (not for points -- just for learning). The assignment is to create a recursive "12-days-of-chirstmas" program

This is my current program

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
void p(std::string v){std::cout<<v;}
std::string v[13] = {"A Partridge in a Pear Tree.\n\n","2 Turtle Doves\n","3 French Hens\n","4 Colly Birds\n","5 Gold Rings\n","6 Geese-a-Laying\n","7 Swans-a-Swimming\n","8 Maids-a-Milking\n","9 Ladies Dancing\n","10 Lords-a-Leaping\n","11 Pipers Piping\n","12 Drummers Drumming\n",""};
int main(){
    switch(v[12].length()){
        case 12:system("pause"); return 0;
        case 11:p(v[11]);
        case 10:p(v[10]);
        case 9: p(v[9]);
        case 8: p(v[8]);
        case 7: p(v[7]);
        case 6: p(v[6]);
        case 5: p(v[5]);
        case 4: p(v[4]);
        case 3: p(v[3]);
        case 2: p(v[2]);
        case 1: p(v[1]);
        case 0: p(v[0]); 
    }v[12] += "0";
    main();
}
```

I would like to pass in the array of verses as an argument to main instead of declaring it above the function.  I know, not the most memory/stack conscious. But it would eliminate a line :)

Comment: Why do you want to do this, and why do you have to do it to `main`?

Comment: A `main()` function taking only an `int` or an array is not a valid form of `main()` in standard C++. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: int a[1] is a single element in an array not an array of one element

Comment: If your intention is to set defaults (or initialize the array being passed in) - then you have to do it inside main function.

Comment: It is forbidden to call `main()` in a C++ program.  You need to create another function that is recursive.

Comment: "forbidden"? Well, it compiles/runs as it is with Visual Studio Pro...

Comment: @Michael: It is not allowed by the standard. You should move all your logic into another function that you are allowed to call recursively.

Comment: [TIL!](http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/CppCodingStandard.html)

Comment: @Michael: That's not what we mean. That's somebodies (rather elaborate) coding standard, we're talking about the *language standard*, the document that defines what C++ is.

Comment: Of course, whether or not your professor wants standard C++/is a good professor is another matter.

Comment: @GMan **long blink** ahh... light bulb.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) explains it best:

> In C++ it is not possible to pass a
>   complete block of memory by value as a
>   parameter to a function, but we are
>   allowed to pass its address.

That's why you can declare a function with

```
void foo (int bar[]);
```

but you can't declare

```
void foo (int bar[] = {0 ,1});
```

It has nothing to do with `main()`.

Comment: Great link and simple explanation. Upvote for you (arg! no upvote as a function of low reputation)

Comment: With C++0x you can! But that array would be destroyed when it will goes out of scope.

Answer (score 8):

Addressing the array passing rather than the unlikely use of main(), due to the array really being passed as a pointer, you can do it like this:

```
int defaultInit[2] = {0,1}; // {0,1} means 2 elements for the array.

int f(int arg[2] = defaultInit)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `main()` function should only receive none or two parameters the quantity of command line arguments and the arguments itself.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
}
```

Where `argc` is the quantity of arguments and `argv` is one array of C-strings containing the arguments.

**EDIT:**

He changed the focus.
You can reduce the number of lines doing this:

```
void loop(int i) { 
    if (i < 0) { v[12] += "0"; return; }
    p(v[i]);
    loop(i-1);
}
int main() {
    if (v[12].size() == 12) return;
    loop(v[12].size());
    main();
}
```

Comment: So, main cannot receive default arguments, as a constructor, or other function can? example: int main(int a=5){}

Comment: It is not standard. But you can do many things there for reducing the number of lines. A `for` for example will reduce so much lines.

Comment: A `for` would be quite beneficial! Unfortunately, one of the requirements was "no looping" as he is trying to teach us the power of recursion.

Comment: Ok I'll not play with your toy anymore :)

Comment: I'm tempted to turn that last edit in, but my _dang conscience_ won't let me

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int go(int);
int main( int argc, char*argv[]) {
go(0);
}
int go(int argc) {
const char* lyrics[] = {...};
printf("On the %d%s day of Christmas\nmy true love gave to me\n",argc,
  argc==1?"st":argc==2?"nd":argc==3?"rd":"th" );
for(int i=argc-1;i>0;--i) { printf("%d %s\n",i+1,lyrics[i]); }
printf("%s\n\n",lyrics[0]);

if( argc < 12 ) go(argc+1);
return 0;
}
```