# How to use a default argument for std::array? "array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer"

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, default-value, stdarray

My constructor takes an `std::array`. I'm trying to give it a default value, but calling the constructor without an argument gives this error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic-errors test.cpp Position.cpp -o test
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:14:29: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
  Position *y = new Position();
                             ^
test.cpp:14:29: error: too many initializers for ‘std::array<unsigned char, 8ul>’
```

Line numbers are different. This is my code:

```
// test.cpp
int main() {
    Position *x = new Position({1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}); // works
    Position *y = new Position(); // does not work
}

// Position.cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include "Position.h"
Position::Position( std::array<uint8_t,8> columns_ ) {
    columns = columns_;
}

// Position.h
#ifndef POSITION_H
#define POSITION_H
#include <array>
class Position {
    public:
    Position( std::array<uint8_t,8> = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} );
    private:
    std::array<uint8_t,8> columns;
};
#endif
```

What have I got wrong?

Comment: Why don't put an overload `Position::Position()`?

Comment: This cannot be done, [Passing an array as a parameter with default values into int main()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894094/passing-an-array-as-a-parameter-with-default-values-into-int-main)

Comment: @cpp he's not trying to do that. He wants a default value for an argument to a *constructor*, not main.

Comment: @Adam, I know, I refered to the answer of this question, where it is said, that it is not possible to pass a complete block of memory by value as a parameter to a function, and that it has nothing to do with main().

Comment: @cpp if you were named `cpp11` you wouldn't say that.

Answer (score 5):

You need to repeat the type:

```
Position( std::array<uint8_t,8> = std::array<uint8_t,8>{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} );
```

while this (or using double-braces) works, it creates a copy on each caller's side when the default is taken. An overloaded constructor would avoid this kind of code-bloat, hence I'd advice to prefer overloads over default parameters.

Comment: these copies are not optimized away by the compiler? since at the call site the compiler knows whether a default argument was supplied or not.

Comment: @TemplateRex If the implementation of the method ends up in a different translation unit, the compiler has no chance to optimize it. (maybe, just maybe, LTO can come to the rescue but I would never rely on it)

Comment: OK but for STL headers (with their hidden allocators and what not) and other header-only code, this problem does not apply, correct?

Comment: @TemplateRex Even then that's not entirely true. Just because the compiler *could* optimize it away does not mean it actually *does*. Also, in some cases, the language rules make it extra hard to optimize stuff away. And in the overloads, you might even get away with simplifying the implementation even further. But in general it's always a trade-off between code simplicitly, maintainability, efficiency and code size. The knowledge and awareness of what is really happening is what allows you to make informed decisions - but it's always a decision, I don't believe in one-size-fits-all solutions.

Answer (score 4):

double-braces required for the second case to run:

```
Position( std::array<uint8_t,8> = {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}} );
```